# set up email addresses that aren't attached to a user

Tags: email

I need to set up a lot of email addresses on a Linux machine, but I don't want to create a new user account for each one.

The mail can stored in a regular maildir or mbox.  (I'll be checking the mail through some Perl code running on a cronjob.)

How do I do this?

Comment: what mail delevery agent and mail transfer agent are you using?

Answer (score 2):

You can use virtual users (and domains) stored on a database so you don't need to create linux users to the mailboxes and the admin of the mail users and domain is very simple, just adding or removing a record in the database table.

[an example for ubuntu, postfix and mysql](http://www.howtoforge.com/virtual-users-domains-postfix-courier-mysql-squirrelmail-ubuntu-10.04)

Answer (score 1):

The full answer really depends on what mail server program you are using.

For both the `postfix` and `sendmail` you can redirect mail addresses to local accounts using the `/etc/aliases` file: any line of the form `address: unix-account` will deliver email addressed to `address@your.domain` to the mailbox of `unix-account`.  For example, if `/etc/aliases` contains a line like this:

```
postmaster: root
```

then UNIX user `root` will get all the mail addressed to `postmaster@your.domain`, without any need for `postmaster` to exist as a regular UNIX account.

Instead of a UNIX account name, you can specify the full path of a file -- mail will be delivered to that file (in mbox format).  Other redirections are also possible; see `man aliases` for details.

*Note:* after editing `/etc/aliases`, you have to run the command `newaliases` (as root, typically) in order to have the mail server pick up the new addresses.